# Embed unity3d web player in a web browser

Tags: jquery, html, unity-game-engine

I'm building a simple application with Unity, and I need to embed it in a web browser with other html elements. I found this plugin:
http://www.41post.com/3513/programming/embedding-the-unity-web-player-with-jquery

At the beginning it seemed to work, then I found that only my macbook manage to show the Unity application.
I try with a Windows pc, and the unity web player just goes fullscreen and covers all the other elements of the website, then I tried another macbook and a linux computer, and the web browser console gave me this:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///home/path_to_.unity3d file/%%INSTALLIMAGE%%
Uncaught ReferenceError: AutomaticReload is not defined
Invalid App Id: Must be a number or numeric string representing the application id. all.js:57
The "fb-root" div has not been created, auto-creating all.js:57
FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init(). all.js:57
GET chrome-extension://boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILED www-embed-player.js:140
GET chrome-extension://dliochdbjfkdbacpmhlcpmleaejidimm/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILED www-embed-player.js:140
GET chrome-extension://hfaagokkkhdbgiakmmlclaapfelnkoah/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILED www-embed-player.js:140
GET chrome-extension://fmfcbgogabcbclcofgocippekhfcmgfj/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILED www-embed-player.js:140
GET chrome-extension://enhhojjnijigcajfphajepfemndkmdlo/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILED www-embed-player.js:140
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type image/*:   "https://s3.amazonaws.com/agilecrm/panel/uploaded-logo/1400137616110?id=upload-container". livechat-v2.js:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: YT is not defined
```

The browser I'm talking about is Chrome, in all the computers.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

EDIT: I have disabled all the extension/plugin that may interfere with the browser.

Comment: Is there any reason you're using jQuery to embed it? Look at the source for the "Default" webplayer build too see how it's normally embedded in a page.

Comment: I'm pretty new to this stuff, I read somewhere that this was the only method to make a webpage with html elements and a unity web player.

Can you please link me a source or something?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You don't need an external source, just click build when you select the Webplayer platform and you'll get and HTML file.

Comment: I have tryed your method but I get the same error in the same computers(I have imported the html file with an iframe. Hope that's a good way)...

Comment: Did the html file _by itself_ cause an error?

Comment: No. I mean, in my macbook it works fine. In my linux pc it simply does not load anything. Without any error. I only see the header/footer: 'Unity web player' 'createdd with unity', the rest is just blank. 
If i try to import this in my website I get the errors in the first post!

Answer (score 0):

When you build for the web, two file are generated. A unity file containing the game itself, and a placeholder .html file. Just open this last html file and explore how game is embedded.